# Latex escaping in MatPlotlib

Tags: matplotlib, tex

There are a number of situations where it is useful to set `matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`. In this case, special LaTeX characters such as `%` have to be escaped in places like axis labels. Is there a function built in to `matplotlib` for escaping LaTeX symbols?

There is a hint of such a thing in the docs [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#writing-mathematical-expressions) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#troubleshooting), but no clear mention.

The specific problem I am trying to tackle is using a `matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter`, where a custom symbol (`symbol=r'\%'`) must be used if `rcParams['text.usetex']` is true. I am trying to add a PR that will escape the percent symbol in `PercentFormatter` if `rcParams['text.usetex']` is enabled, but it does not make sense to only check for the percent symbol in that case, so I would like to escape the entire symbol string.

Comment: @tcaswell. Is there any chance you know the answer to this?

Comment: I do not know of such a auto-escaper.

Comment: @tcaswell Worth a PR? The new PR I made is probably not the only possible use-case for such a thing.

Comment: @Tyilo. By what stretch of the imagination is that a duplicate?

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry, I guess I didn't fully read your question :/